# SCM: Wiki + Forum + ticket System

Tags: frameworks, wiki, forum, ticket-system

Is there any open source framework that encapsulates: a `Wiki`, `Forum` and a `ticket system`. Something like a software configuration Manager (SCM).

Looking for something very similar to *sourceforge* offers to project owners.

I'm looking to give support to a small *private* web software project. I keep finding separate implementations of these features.

If there are commercial products it would be nice to hear from them too.

`Wordpress` might be an option.

[image: sourcefourge]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It offers a Wiki, Boards (=Forum), Issue tracking.

Another popular alternative would be [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) which offers Wiki and Issue tracking. For forums there exists a [plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DiscussionPlugin) (The plugin is not actively developed anymore?).

Comment: Can them be password protected?

Comment: Yes, both have flexible role based access control.